# PictureBox change Image form Resources

Tags: c#, resources, picturebox

i want to change an Image in my picturebox, if
an value reaches "5" and further, that's why i use switch.
So i embedded my pictures in the resources.
But i don't know any commands like that.

here is my code, i hope anybody can solve my problem.

```
switch (ButtonPlus1)
{
case5:
    pictureBox1.Image = TraitCalc.Properties.Resources.(my_picture.png);
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int caseSwitch = 1;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
 case 1: 
    Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
    break;
 case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
    break;
 default:
    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    break;
}
```

Maybe this will help you?

What value have ButtonPlus1? 5?

Comment: dont have enough reputations, after this question .... But here is the solution: Instead of TraitCalc.Propories.Resources -> TraitCalc.Resources.yourImg;